# persistence scope failure?

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, persistence

I did follow exactly as per spec in one of search 8.2.2 Persistence Unit Scope,
but it failed in throwing exception like

```
15:08:09,956 WARNING [FileZippedJarVisitor] Unable to find file (ignored): file:entities1.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: entities1.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
...similarly other one too
```

Here is the structure of ear:

```
    |-ear--
           |-lib--|... some libs ...
           |      |--my-persistence-xml.jar
              |--entities1.jar
              |--entities2.jar

           |-ejb-1.jar
           |-web-1.war
```

Here is the persistence:

```xml
    <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/mypu</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>entities1.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>entities2.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

`persistence.xml` should be placed in `META-INF` folder of your `ejb-jar` module. In this case you can use `persistence.xml` without `<jar-file>`. All entites will be registered automaticaly.

If you want use `<jar-file>` then path should be

```
<jar-file>../../entities1.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>../../entities2.jar</jar-file>
```

what means `my-persistence-xml.jar`. It's `jar` or `xml`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. my-persistence-xml.jar holds only persistence unit under META-INF, but all entities are available on entities1.jar and entities2.jar.

Comment: It should also have `ejb-jar.xml` in META-INF

Comment: I moved my-persistence-xml.jar from lib to ear level but still is not recognizing as valid path.

Comment: it is scanning if i give absolute path of the jars. Please throw some light on this.

Comment: It's scanning all entities If I give jboss absolute path of the jar C:\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\my-app\deploy\com.app.ear\lib\entities1.jar, (2). C:\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\my-app\deploy\com.app.ear\lib\entities2.jar. Please throw me an idea to resolve this abs path.

Comment: Your `my-persistence-xml.jar` can't see another `jars`, becouse they are not in classpath of `my-persistence-xml.jar`. Try to add this `entities1.jar` and `entities2.jar` to classpath of `my-persistence-xml.jar`

Comment: add `../entities1.jar;../entities1.jar` to classpath in MANIFEST.MF in my-persistence-xml.jar